# multiselect not working while passing to html using javascript(inner html)

Tags: javascript, html

html tag where i am calling showDiv() function

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 margin-y">
           <div class="width">
              <label class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">Select your preference<span>*</span></label>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">
                 <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="req_prp_type" name="req_prp_type" onchange="return showDiv();" required>
                       <option value="">Please Select</option>
                       <?php echo $this->home_model->get_dropdown('prp_type')?>
                    </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="req_prp_mode" name="req_prp_mode" onchange="return showDiv();" required>
                       <option value="">Please Select</option>
                       <?php echo $this->home_model->get_dropdown('prp_mode')?>
                    </select>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv($value) {
    var req_prp_type = $('#req_prp_type').val();
    var req_prp_mode = $('#req_prp_mode').val();
    if (req_prp_type != '' && req_prp_mode != '') {
        if ((req_prp_type == 1 && req_prp_mode == 1) || (req_prp_type == 1 && req_prp_mode == 2)) {
            $("#data").html('<div class="col-xs-12 margin-y"><div class="width"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 margin-y"><div class="width"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10"><div class="col-xs-12 margin-y"><label class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Commercial Type</label><select class="form-control ddlCars col-xs-6" multiple="multiple"><?php echo $this->home_model->get_dropdown('
                commercial_type ')?></select></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="col-xs-12 margin-y"><label class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Condition</label><select class="form-control ddlCars col-xs-6" multiple="multiple">><?php echo $this->home_model->get_dropdown('
                pri_condition ')?> </select></div>');
        }

    }

}
```

this function is bootstrap multiple select  js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ddlCars').multiselect();
    $('.ddlCars1').multiselect({
        numberDisplayed: 1,

    });
    $('.ddlCars').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true
    });
    $('.ddlCars').multiselect({
        nonSelectedText: 'Select'
    });
});
$('.amItem').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

i have used those .css and .js

assets/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">

assets/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js">

Comment: Inspect the html and check if the attribute is set properly

Comment: When do you call showDiv? You likely need to trigger the multiselect after inserting

Comment: requirement:576 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (requirement:576)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.9.1.js:103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had multiple jquery.js called in my view. I have deleted multiple and have kept one. I have called my show_div function and my multiselect function in a single tag script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle perfect work on this

https://jsfiddle.net/jdndnd9k/

```
// HTML Part
<a id="show" href=Javascript:void(0);>Show</a>
<div id="div_show" style="display:none;">
    <select id="data" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>

// JS Part
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#div_show").show();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data').multiselect();
});
```

if now any problem then check your console and solve error.

Comment: we have tried it and we are not getting the required output because we are trying to make dropdown in js